# как организовать поиск в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

День добрый

Есть задача сделать поиск по файлам в папке используя `glob` 
сам поиск я организовал, но если он находит несколько значений, нужно чтобы следующая инетация поиска была по тем значениям, которые были найдены в предыдущем.

Поиск завёрнут в `while` - цикл, но увы, из него он ничего не хочет в сторонний список выкладывать. Условие цикла `True` возможно в этом ошибка

Как это правильно организовать?

```
import glob
import os.path
from pprint import pprint

def get_name(input_value):
    results = list()
    migrations = 'Migrations'
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(migrations,  "*" + str(input_value) + "*" + ".sql"))
    for file in files:
        results.append(file.split("\n"))
    return results

def main():
    while True:
        input_value = input("Введите что ищем:\n (Регистр значения не имеет) \n")  # вводим поисковый запрос по файлам
        all_results = get_name(input_value)
        if len(all_results) > 1:
            pprint(all_results)
            print("Много значений, ищем дальше! Всего файлов - {}".format(len(all_results)))
    else:
        print("Мы нашли искомое! {}".format(all_results))
main()
```

Comment: Выложили бы код )

Comment: извиняюсь ,обновил вопрос.. :)

Comment: т.е. я правильно понял: вводим что хотим найти, если нашлось больше одного, сохраняем список и предлагаем ввести другой фильтр для поиска среди найденного?

Comment: да, всё верно.. попробовал делать appen внутри цикла, чтобы он найденое сохранял в файл, но это не помогло :/

Answer (score 0):

Вообще Вам бы организовать это в ООП стиле, было бы и красиво, и познавательно, и работало бы, попробуйте так, для начала - поправил Ваш код:

```
import glob
import os.path
from pprint import pprint

def res_get_name():
    results = list()
    def secret_met(input_value):
        migrations = 'Migrations'
        files = glob.glob(os.path.join(migrations,  "*" + str(input_value) + "*" + ".sql"))
        for file in files:
            results.append(file.split("\n"))
        return results
    return secret_met

def main():
    get_name = res_get_name()
    while True:
        input_value = input("Введите что ищем:\n (Регистр значения не имеет) \n")  # вводим поисковый запрос по файлам
        all_results = get_name(input_value)
        if len(all_results) > 1:
            pprint(all_results)
            print("Много значений, ищем дальше! Всего файлов - {}".format(len(all_results)))
        else:
            print("Мы нашли искомое! {}".format(all_results))

main()
```

Только с циклом надо поработать, а то он бесконечный, добавьте обработку, если введете ключевое слово, например "СТОП" цикл завершиться, писал на коленке, ниче не проверял, если не работает, отпишите, поправим